# Is there a netcat like utility that uses unix sockets?

Tags: netcat

netcat is wonderful, let me count the ways -- is to much let me sum up -- tcp/ip4, udp/ip4, tcp/ip6, udp/ip6, but what I need is stream/unix. I could write it in half a day, but If someone has already scratched this itch...

Comment: What do you need that isn't covered by a standard `read` command?

Comment: @jordanm bidirectional io, interactive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Ubuntu I find this in the netcat man page:

```
 -U      Specifies to use UNIX-domain sockets.
```

So it seems netcat already can do what you are asking for.

Comment: Note that on many distros there are two versions of `netcat` - the "traditional" variant, and the BSD variant. If this is your case, you want the BSD variant because it comes with significantly more features, one of them being Unix socket capability.

Answer (score 5):

[Socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) is basically netcat with sockets, serial lines, and reusable connections.